# Select some sets, and union them together to form main set, in a way that minimizes the cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

## Definition

- Set `P={e1,e2,...,en}`,`P` has `n` different elements,enumerated as `ei's` in it.
- Set `I={e1',e2',...,en'}`,`I` has at least one element that is similar to some element of `P`.The number of elements in `I` need not be equal to the number of elements in `P`.
- Each `I` has a weight `Q` associated with it, and that describes the cost to use it .`Q>0`

You have to help me in designing an algorithm, that takes a set `P` as input, and some (say k of them) I sets, denoted by I1,I2,. . . , Ik, and exactly k, Q values, denoted by Q1,Q2,. . . ,Qk. Q1 denots the cost to use set I1, and so on.


You have to choose some I's, say I1,I2,. . . , such that when they all are unioned together, they produce set `P'` and `P` is a subset of that.

Notice that once you find a selection of I's, it has a cost associated with it. 
You also have to make sure that this cost is as **MINIMUM** as possible.

## Input

- input one Set `P`
- input a list of Set `I`,IList={I1,I2,...In}
- input a list of Set `Q`,QList={Q1,Q2,...Qn}
- `Ix` `Qx` are corresponding one by one.

## Output

- `P'` = I<sub>a</sub> union I<sub>b</sub>...union I<sub>n</sub>
- `P' ⊂ P`
- Make the Q<sub>a</sub>+Q<sub>b</sub>...+Q<sub>n</sub> be the min value.

## Also mention the Time and Space Complexity of your algorithm

## Sample Input

```
P={a,b,c}
I1={a,x,y,z} Q1=0.7
I2={b,c,x} Q2=1
I3={b,x,y,z} Q3=2
I4={c,y} Q4=3
I5={a,b,c,y} Q5=9
```

## Sample Output

```
P1 = I1 U I2 COST=Q1+Q2=1.7
P2 = I1 U I3 U I4 COST=Q1+Q3+Q4=5.7
P3 = I5 COST=Q5=9
And:P⊂P1,P⊂P2,P⊂P3
The P COST : 1.7<5.7<9
And then what we want is:
P1 = I1 U I2 COST=Q1+Q2=1.7
```

Comment: This is rather unclear. How do the P come into play? Whats the configuration to be minimised? Should the elements in the I's cover the P and you take just the ones to achieve that?

Comment: sorry for my poor English and express,and I update the question.

Comment: @Paleo Is it also possible that for given I's , there is no way to pick some of them and take their union such that EXACTLY `P` is formed. Maybe in the final union `P'` there are some elements extra than P. What to do about such cases ? Or this case will never happen ?

Comment: @premktiw `P` can be a subset of `P'` ,but `Qa+Qb...+Qn` must be minimum value.

Comment: Is the size of all I's same ?

Comment: @premktiw No,they can be different. :) Thanks for your help~

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output. Your description is ... convoluted. As written, it's rather difficult to figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some suggestion to simplify the problem.

We first duplicate all the `I` sets, and lets call them `I1'`, `I2'`, `.` `.` `.`

Now, first job that we should do is to remove the unwanted elements from duplicated `I'` sets. Here unwanted means the elements which will not contribute towards the main set `P`.

We discard all those `I'` sets which do not have even a single element of `P`.

Now suppose `P` has some `n` elements in it, we now know definitely that `I'` sets are nothing but subsets of the main set, and every subset has a cost Q<sub>i</sub> associated with it.

We just have to pick some subsets such that they together cover the main set.
Subject to the minimum cost.

We will denote the main set and subsets using bit based notation.

If the set `P` has `n` elements in it, we will have n bits in the representation.
So the main set will be denoted by <1,1,...1> (`n` 1's).
And it's subsets will be denoted by bitset, having some 1's absent from the bitset of main set. Because `I's` are also subsets, they will also have some binary representation denoting the subset they are representing.

To solve the problem efficiently, let's make an assumption that there is so much of memory available, that if the bitset is treated as a number in binary, we can index the bitsets, to some memory location in constant time.

This means that, if we have, suppose `n = 4`, all the subsets can be represented
by different values from 0 to 15 (see their binary representation from 0000(empty set) to 1111(main set), when element at position `i` of main array is present in a subset we put a 1 at that position in the bitset). And similarly when `n` is larger.

Now, having the bitset based notation for the set, the Union of two sets denoted by bitset `b1` and `b2` will be denoted by `b1|b2`. where `|` is bitwise OR operation.

Of course, we will not require so many memory locations, as not all the subsets of parent set will be available as `I's`.

**Algorithm** **:**

The algorithmic idea used here is bitset based Dynamic Programming.

Assume we have a big array, namely `COST`, where `COST[j]` represents the cost to have the subset, represented by bitset notation of `j`.

To start with the algorithm, we first put the cost to choose given subsets (in terms of `I's`), in their respective indices in `COST` array, and at all the other locations we put a very large value, say `INF`.

What we have to do is, to fill the array appropriately, and then once it is filled properly, we will get the answer to minimum cost by looking at the value `COST[k]` where `k` has all bits set, in binary representation.

Now we will focus on how to fill the array properly.

This is rather easy task, we will iterate the `COST` array, `K` no. of times where `K` is the no. of `I'`-sets we have.

For every `I's` set, let's call it's binary representation `BI'`.
we OR the bit representation of `BI'` and current index(`idx`), and what we get is the new set which is the UNION of the set represented by current index, and `BI'`, let's call this new set as `S'` and it's final binary representation as `BS'`.

We will look at the `COST[BS']`, and if we see that this `COST` is larger than `COST[BI'] + COST[idx]`, we will update the value at the `COST[BS']`.

In similar way we proceed, and at the end of the run, we get the minimum cost at `COST[BP]`, where `BP` is the bitset for `P`.

In order to track the participating `I's`, who actually contributed in the formation of `P`, we can take a note, while updating any index.

**TIME COMPLEXITY** **:** O(2^n * K), where `K` is the no. of `I` sets, and `n` is the no. of elements in `P`.

**Space Complexity** **:** O(2^n)

NOTE : Because of the assumption, that the bit-representation are directly indexable, the solution may not be very much feasible for large values of `n` and `k`.